# Update table in database with ListBox data one-by-one

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a table which lists items to `buy` in the database of a hospital and these are the fields :

`ID | Medicine Name | Stock`

I have two `listbox` objects in my program. `ListBox 1` displays values from the database and `ListBox 2` displays the values which are selected in `ListBox 1`. When the user clicks the button, I want to save data in table buy, the question is how do I save one-by-one based value in `ListBox 2` ? And also ask also stock one by one.

Comment: Not clear what you want, but are you trying to iterate over the selected values of your listbox or... ?

Comment: Do you want only one value to be selected at a time?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: What is "stock" in this context? (I'm editing)

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET...?

Comment: @Shaharyar some value

Comment: @KerenCaelen I don't make code

Comment: @ParasDPain stock this it. stock medicine. Sorry I'm bad english.

Comment: @Konamiman WinForms.

Comment: So you want to add data to the `BUY` table from `ListBox2` when the user clicks the button? And you want the items with the same name to only add 1 to the stock value?
Don't worry about the English, You can always use Google translate to better word what you want to say.

Comment: @ParasDPain when click button, then all value in `ListBox 2`, I want to insert based it and ask stock based name medicine.

Comment: Oh Okey so you want to check in the table if there is enough stock?

Comment: @ParasDPain no, just insert :)

Comment: I see so insert the items from the ListBox to the Table

Comment: @ParasDPain how to ask stock one by one based value `listbox` selected?